MAUI:IOS:- Getting error while creating IPA file for distribution of archive
I am getting the following error when I distribute the archive to the app store/ad hoc channel.
Could not create IPA file for distribution of the archive "App_Name".
The "CreateAssetPack" task was not given a value for the required parameter "source".
When I publish the App from the visual studio, its successfully done. After publishing App, when try to distribute on Ad hoc or App Store channel, then getting the above mentioned error.
From the error, it seems like some assets are missing. I spent  lot of time but could not find out what asset/resource is missing. Could anyone please guide me how to debug this issue or know any workaround?


I shared cproj file assets section, I am wondering, if I am missing anything here.

What's the version of your XCode  and Visual studio? And you can also try the command line first.

Thanks for your comment. That issue was fixed when I upgrade the XCode to latest version. I could not figure out the actual cause but i get rid from this error.

Are you saying your problem is solved? Congrats. :)

Hi @jabar, as a summary, I will post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems. Thanks for your support for Maui. :)

Thanks for that. Issue was fixed after upgrading XCode.


That issue was fixed when I upgrade the XCode to latest version. I
could not figure out the actual cause but i get rid from this error.

For this problem, we can upgrade the XCode to latest version and try again.
